# DllImport with out SafeHandle results in MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I wrote a wrapper class to access an unmanaged lib in c# for QuickUsb. For the full fledged implementation see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Assimilater/c45b4dc284fdb4fd59b8388212d9e843).

The main points of interest to this question are the following parts:

```
public class QuickUsbPort
{
    private class SafeQuickUsbHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        [DllImport("QuickUsb.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] static extern
            int QuickUsbClose(IntPtr handle);

        public SafeQuickUsbHandle(IntPtr handle) : base(true)
        {
            SetHandle(handle);
        }

        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return QuickUsbClose(handle) != 0;
        }
    }

    private static class NativeLib
    {
        [DllImport("QuickUsb.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] static extern
            int QuickUsbOpen(out SafeQuickUsbHandle handle, string deviceName);

        public static SafeQuickUsbHandle Open(string deviceName)
        {
            if (QuickUsbOpen(out SafeQuickUsbHandle handle, deviceName) == 0)
            {
                throw new QuickUsbException("Open", new List<Tuple<string, string>>
                {
                    new Tuple<string, string>("deviceName", deviceName),
                });
            }
            return handle;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems there is a problem marshaling `handle` as a `SafeQuickUsbHandle` as upon calling `Open()` this code throws a `MissingMethodException`. However the following modification throws no such exception:

```
        [DllImport("QuickUsb.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] static extern
            int QuickUsbOpen(out IntPtr handle, string deviceName);

        public static SafeQuickUsbHandle Open(string deviceName)
        {
            if (QuickUsbOpen(out IntPtr handle, deviceName) == 0)
            {
                throw new QuickUsbException("Open", new List<Tuple<string, string>>
                {
                    new Tuple<string, string>("deviceName", deviceName),
                });
            }
            return new SafeQuickUsbHandle(handle);
        }
```

So I'm wondering if I'm missing some aspect of my `SafeQuickUsbHandle` implementation to allow c# to properly marshal and dispose of the handle.

Note that in the dll, handle is pointer to a handle:

```
/// <param name="handle">
/// A PQHANDLE that points to a QHANDLE in which to place the new device ID.
/// If successful, hDevice will contain the new QHANDLE</param>
```

Comment: Any variable needs memory.  When calling a method (or dll) the parameter list get put on the execution stack and when the function returns the execution stack is disposed. So you loose any return variables because the variable is on the stack.   So any OUT declarations you must allocate the memory in the calling method.  I would like to see the c language code because I suspect you are are using a pointer and that is why the code works with 2nd method.

Comment: @jdweng I don't have access to the c code, but yes it's a pointer. QuickUsbOpen creates a handle and returns it as an out parameter rather than a return value. The return value indicates success. By putting the typename in the function call is shorthand for defining the handle beforehand and then passing it to the function so it's on the stack. And maybe that's the problem. Maybe there isn't a way to resolve this other than I have done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must provide a public parameterless constructor to a class that derives from [SafeHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx), especially when you it with p/invoke, as defined here: [SafeHandle](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/08/12/safehandle/)

> Your subclass of SafeHandle is only required to provide three methods
>
> .ctor() – A default constructor that initializes the SafeHandle.  This
>   method is used by P/Invoke when it returns a SafeHandle to your
>   process
>
> bool IsInvalid { get; } – a property to determine if the
>   current value of the handle is valid or not
>
> bool ReleaseHandle() –
>   clean up the contained resource

p/invoke will set the value magically anyway. It's also in the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx):

> When you inherit from SafeHandle, you must override the following
>   members: IsInvalid and ReleaseHandle. You should also provide a
>   default constructor that calls the base constructor with a value that
>   represent an invalid handle value, and a Boolean value indicating
>   whether the native handle is owned by the SafeHandle and consequently
>   should be freed when that SafeHandle has been disposed.

Since `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` doesn't define a public parameterless constructor, you must do it.

Comment: Must have missed that detail (lots of tutorials, that's my real problem lol). Good call, though I believe even if `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` provided a public parameterless constructor I would still need to implement my own as constructors aren't inherited in c#

Comment: For any future users that pass by here: it turns out `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid` is the wrong chain to use for QuickUsb as zero is a valid value. As such I inherted directly from SafeHandle and added `public override bool IsInvalid { get { return handle.ToInt32() < 0; } }`

Comment: Apparently the constructor does not have to be `public`, a `private` one works for me aswell (.NET 4.5.1 / .NET Standard 2.0), awesome since it doesn't clutter the public interface.